# Add data to a dynamic row from database

Tags: dynamic, save, row

So for example i have a form where the data is added dynamically. When I click on a "+" there comes one more row, where i can add more data. And so on...
Like in this example.

```js
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow()
{
    console.log( 'hi');
    var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;
    
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    x.appendChild( new_row );
}
```

```html
<div id="POItablediv">
    <input type="button" id="addPOIbutton" value="Add POIs"/><br/><br/>
    <table id="POITable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>POI</td>
            <td>Latitude</td>
            <td>Longitude</td>
            <td>Delete?</td>
            <td>Add Rows?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox"/></td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" readonly=true/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add More POIs" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

So how can i save this data on a database, and then read this. I also need to save the count of the row´s. Is this even possible with JS?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that your question is a little broad: there are many ways to store your data in some kind of backend. One standard way would be to send your data over to an http server with an ajax request. Another way would be to save your data locally in the storage of the browser. Please clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. 

Sorry for my confuse question, englisch is not my native language. I would like to send the data via ajax to the server. 

What I try to achive is a programm which can save recipes. The form for the amount of ingredients should be expandable dynamically like in the example. My problem is that I don´t know how to save this fields which are generated dynamically. And I also don´t know how to read them out again, when they are saved. For example when the user wants to change something on his recipe.

Comment: I don't think that question can be answered on StackOverlow - it's still to broad. Just a few hints: on the server side, you have to choose a framework to save your data: if you want to stay with `js`, you can use `node` and `mongoDb`, `php` and `mysql` is another popular combination. On the client side, you probably need a _view model_, look at [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) for some examples. They even have an [example without a framework](http://todomvc.com/examples/vanillajs/). Good look, there is much to learn!

Comment: Okay thank you. I already know how to do this with php an mysql. But i thought it would be more fancy to do this dynamically. Thank for the help ;)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, you surely can do this dynamically - I didn't say you'll have to render `html` with `php`. There surely are frameworks for rest apis in `php`, so you'll only send asynchronous http requests with json data to load/store/modify your data. You still need some kind of model for your ui.

Comment: Do you have an example for such a http request? Is this AJAX? Ia am a guy from the PHP corner ;)
Right now I am not at the stage of doing UI for this project. I only want to have a quick overview of the functionality and some example easy ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Okay I´ve just found this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp looks like magic just happend. Never knew there is this way... Thank you

Comment: So I just need to save the ingredients as JS object and then save it to JSON and then send it to the server? And then I can use it as an array for javascript and also for php in a further stage like in the readout of the recipe?

Comment: I think you got the idea! You'll have to think of what kind of storage to use on the server - if you're using a SQL database you have read/parse in the json again and store it in your recipe table.